# How to handle dynamic DropDown button in flutter and store dropdown on change data

Tags: flutter

Please some explain with example

i have try many times but i have nor solved this problem please help me anyone . continuesly work on this from 2 days
Here is my requirement, when I click the dropicon and then store th vaue in list wiht show this value but i have faced error,
i need help please support me

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      height: 12.h,
    ),
    Text(textFieldController.customTextFieldList[0].data123[index].name,style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff3A456E,),fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,fontSize: 18.sp)),
    SizedBox(
      height: 10.h,
    ),
    Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xfff5f5f5),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.w),
      child: DropdownButton(
        hint: const Text("Select"),
        value:  listValues.isNotEmpty ?  listValues[index] : null,
        isExpanded: true,
        elevation: 0,
        underline: Container(),
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.arrow_drop_down,
          size: 35,
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),
        items: textFieldController.customTextFieldList[0].data123[index].options.map((Options12 item) {
          return DropdownMenuItem(
            value: item.value,
            child: Text(item.value.toString()),
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (newValue) {

          if(listValues.isEmpty){
            listValues.addAll(listKeys);
          }
          listValues.removeAt(index);
          listValues.insert(index, newValue!);
         },
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I handle dynamic dropdown button show on screen, get data, and show in hint text:

```
DropdownButton(
  hint: const Text("Select"),
  value:  listValues.isNotEmpty ? listValues[index].indexOf("YESYES-")!=-1?null : listValues[index] : null,
  isExpanded: true,
  elevation: 0,
  underline: Container(),
  icon: const Icon(
    Icons.arrow_drop_down,
    size: 35,
    color: Colors.blueAccent,
  ),
  items: textFieldController.customTextFieldList[0].data123[index].options.map((Options12 item) {
    if (listIDValues.isEmpty) {
      listIDValues.addAll(listKeys);
    }

    return DropdownMenuItem(
      key: Key(item.id.toString()),
      value: item.value,
      onTap: () {
        if (listIDValues.elementAt(index) != null) {
          listIDValues.removeAt(index);
          listIDValues.insert(index, item.id.toString());
        }

        print("option id "+item.id.toString());
      },
      child: Text(item.value.toString()),
    );
  }).toList(),
  onChanged: (newValue) {
    setState(() {
  });

  showSelectValue = false;
  print("on change called ");

  if (listValues.isEmpty) {
    print("if key "+listKeys.toString());
    listValues.addAll(listKeys);
    listIDValues.addAll(listKeys);
  }
  if (showSelectValue == false) {
    listValues.removeAt(index);
    listValues.insert(index, newValue!);
  }
},
)
```

Comment: 100% sure solved your problem